# Why is it important to have a receptacle next to load centers?

Tags: wiring

Why is there a receptacle next to a load center? Is it necessary to have this circuit dedicated to one breaker by itself? Or can I pigtail it at the load center?

Answer (score 4):

#### Convenience

It is simply convenient to have a functional receptacle near the panel to plug in equipment. No requirement as far as I know, but trivially easy to add and very useful.

No reason that it needs to be dedicated unless it is being used for a specific appliance with high current requirements. But if it is just a convenience receptacle with nothing normally plugged into it then it can be on any circuit that itself can be shared - i.e., that rules out the kitchen countertop receptacle circuits and bathroom receptacle circuit. However, as Harper noted, there are advantages at times to having this receptacle be on a circuit all by itself, so if you can spare a circuit to do that, it is a good idea - and just the cost of an extra breaker - to put this receptacle on its own circuit.

Also keep in mind that depending on location it will likely require AFCI and/or GFCI, though if the receptacle is already in place then you normally don't need to upgrade it unless you are making changes to the circuit.

Comment: I agree, in industrial facilities where controls are needed in that case we need an outlet but in a residential setting we put them in because it is a cheap location to add a receptacle.+

Answer (score 3):

I call it the "Electrician's receptacle". That is there so the electrician can down every other circuit in the panel, and still have a place to plug in his portable light, and extension cord for getting power elsewhere in the building so he can work there.

A big part of this circuit is keeping it *dog simple*. That's so he can quickly inspect it, see that it only connects to the one thing, and thus be assured that the rest of the house is off.

If you are out of panel spaces, that is a separate problem and you should solve it separately. Cannibalizing the electrician's outlet is not the worst thing you can do, but you might as well **deal head-on** with the "no spaces left problem, because having the freedom to add any circuits you please is *much, much better* than being forced into a series of worse and worse compromises.  Electricity is for using.